# Variable value not updating in service

Tags: angular

I have built the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
    url = 'api address';
    element_id;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  public getMenus(){
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
  public getData(element_id){
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
  public change_val(element_id){
    console.log('This ' + element_id + " is in the service");
    this.element_id = element_id;
  }
}
```

Two things of note in the service:

1. A variable, **element_id**, is declared, but not given any value
2. The last function, ***change_val(element_id)***, changes the value of element_id when it is run. Its being defined in the service because it is used in other components.

The service is shared across two components that also use **element_id**:

*nav.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  menus;
  constructor(private api: ApiService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getMenus().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      //console.log(data);
      this.menus = data;
  });
  }
 public change_val(element_id){
    console.log("This " + element_id + " comes from nav.component")
    this.api.element_id = element_id
 }
}
```

and

*content.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {
  content;
  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }
  ngOnInit(){
    return this.api.getData(this.api.element_id).subscribe(res => {
    this.content = res[this.api.element_id];
  });
}
}
```

The ***change_val()*** function is run and **element_id** is given a value by a simple (click):

*nav.component.html*

```
<div *ngFor="let menu of menus; index as id">
    <ul>
        <li><button (click)="change_val(id)">{{menu['course-lesson-name']}}</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my issue:

**element_id** is working fine and has the correct value in *nav.component.ts*, but isnt being passed (updated) whatsoever to *api.service.ts*. This is bad because it is stopping the content from the content component from updating.

What am I missing? Im assuming I likely have a reference wrong somewhere, but need another set of eyes.

Comment: I've just set up a quick StackBlitz based on your code and api gets the element_id https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwyfqj

Comment: Yes, the nav portion works just fine, but the variable value isnt also being updated in the service, only in the nav component. I can see this because content.ts uses the variable value from service and its not working.

Comment: See stackblitz. The service variable is updated. It is set in nav and displayed in app component.

Comment: Yes, I see that now and missed it prior. Now that those two are working, any idea why the same element_id will not update in the content component?

Comment: If you add {{element_id]] to content component template do you not see the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

in `nav.component.ts` why don't call the method from the service instead of just directly changing the value.If you are changing the value of the variable element_id dirrectly from the `nav.component.ts` what is the use of `change_val()` in the service then

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  menus;
  constructor(private api: ApiService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.api.getMenus().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
      //console.log(data);
      this.menus = data;
  });
  }
 public change_val(element_id){
    console.log("This " + element_id + " comes from nav.component")
    this.api.change_val(element_id)
 }
}
```